# Removing new line '\n' from the output of python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using python Beautiful soup to get the contents of:

```
<div class="path">
    <a href="#"> abc</a>
    <a href="#"> def</a>
    <a href="#"> ghi</a>
</div>
```

My code is as follows:

```
html_doc="""<div class="path">
    <a href="#"> abc</a>
    <a href="#"> def</a>
    <a href="#"> ghi</a>
</div>"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

path = soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'path'})
breadcrum = path.findAll(text=True)

print breadcrum
```

The output is as follow,

```
[u'\n', u'abc', u'\n', u'def', u'\n', u'ghi',u'\n']
```

How can I only get the result in this form: `abc,def,ghi` as a single string?

Also I want to know about the output so obtained.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do this:

```
breadcrum = [item.strip() for item in breadcrum if str(item)]
```

The `if str(item)` will take care of getting rid of the empty list items after stripping the new line characters.

If you want to join the strings, then do:

```
','.join(breadcrum)
```

This will give you `abc,def,ghi`

**EDIT**

Although the above gives you what you want, as pointed out by others in the thread, the way you are using BS to extract anchor texts is not correct. Once you have the `div` of your interest, you should be using it to get it's children and then get the anchor text. As:

```
path = soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'path'})
anchors = path.find_all('a')
data = []
for ele in anchors:
    data.append(ele.text)
```

And then do a `','.join(data)`

Comment: `item.rstrip('\n')` would be more explicit to the intent of the operation.

Comment: Now the output is:u',abc,,def,,ghi,'??

Comment: This will fail if there is some other text in the `div` and clearly beats the point of using BS.

Comment: @thefourtheye Agreed, updated the answer to reflect that

Comment: @shaktimaan And I have a better version of what exactly you have, in my answer :) Since yours is accepted I am deleting mine.

Comment: I don't understand. This can be done by simple list comprehension, can it not? Why the need to append to a new list?

Answer (score 7):

If you just strip items in breadcrum you would end up with empty item in your list.  You can either do as shaktimaan suggested and then use

```
breadcrum = filter(None, breadcrum)
```

Or you can strip them all before hand (in html_doc):

```
mystring = mystring.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')
```

Either way to get your string output, do something like this:

```
','.join(breadcrum)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, just combine `strip` and list comprehension.

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup

ofile = open("test.html", "r")
soup = bsoup(ofile)

res = ",".join([a.get_text().strip() for a in soup.find("div", class_="path").find_all("a")])
print res
```

**Result:**

```
abc,def,ghi
[Finished in 0.2s]
```