# How to remove escaped characters from soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is my code:

```
article_edit_page = s.get(article_url, data=payload).text
article_edit_soup = BeautifulSoup(article_edit_page, 'lxml')
    for thing in article_edit_soup.findAll("textarea", {"name":"article"}):
        f.write(str(thing.contents))
```

The output given is:

`["\r\nDallas Area Rapid Transit is adding more officer patrols and increasing the number of security guards as part of its ongoing effort to improve security throughout the system.\r\n\r\nAdditional police officers have been assigned to the three transit facilities in the West End section of Downtown Dallas — West End Station"]`

I tried using `.strip()` but nothing changes, and `''.join()` only removes escaped characters from the first line.

I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890807/removing-new-line-n-from-the-output-of-python-beautifulsoup) , but gives me the same results.

EDIT: I dont want to convert my escaped characters I want to remove them. When I put `get_text` instead of `contents`, my output is:

Dallas Area Rapid Transit is adding more officer patrols and increasing the number of security guards as part of its ongoing effort to improve security throughout the system.

Additional police officers have been assigned to the three transit facilities in the West End section of Downtown Dallas — West End Station

> mind the gap in between

Comment: Have you tried `[e.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '') for e in thing.contents]`? Or you can use `[re.sub('(\n|\r)', '', e) for e in thing.contents]` (be sure to import `re`)

Comment: @odradek The `re.sub` works. Thank you. But for some reason `.replace()` doesn't work.

Comment: Wierd; but i'll post it as answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
f.write(str([re.sub('(\n|\r)', '', e) for e in thing.contents]))
```

Be sure to `import re` first.

Comment: How Can I leave only one of escaped characters ?